# The preposition "by" in "I see by your file"

Tags: prepositions

I often come across some sentences with "by" where I would expect "in" or "on". Examples:

> I see by your file that you are no stranger to the court room, Private Terp. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=4IrkCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT106&dq=%22I%20see%20by%20your%20file%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj9u2_w4zoAhVNgp4KHTcEAS8Q6AEwAHoECAYQAg))
>
> I see by your file that you have had a chequered career. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=1CzRwj5CHLQC&pg=PA192&dq=%22I%20see%20by%20your%20file%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj9u2_w4zoAhVNgp4KHTcEAS8Q6AEwAXoECAAQAg))
>
> I see by your file your nickname is Katey. ([source](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02FHlC8c_KzRwV3DtRMvl_0TOOl5w:1583727179963&tbm=bks&q=inauthor:%22Ivan%20Bosanko%22&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjj9u2_w4zoAhVNgp4KHTcEAS8Q9AgwAnoECAUQBQ))
>
> So, what brings you to New York, Al? I see by your resume, you're from California. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=fd30AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22I%20see%20by%20your%20resume%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-vI2D24zoAhVVoZ4KHWImAT8Q6AEwAHoECAIQAg))
>
> I see by your resume that you graduated from the University of Virginia with a degree in accounting. ([source](https://books.google.com/books?id=hLxNa6bKUdsC&pg=PA29&dq=%22I%20see%20by%20your%20resume%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-vI2D24zoAhVVoZ4KHWImAT8Q6AEwAXoECAUQAg))

More examples can be found on Google Books. I feel though "I see *in* your file/resume" (and maybe "on your file") sounds more natural and "I see *by* your file/resume" sounds odd and even jarring.

Also it seems "I see by his/her file" is much rarer. Why is "by" used here? What are the differences in meaning?

Comment: It's equal to *according to*.

Comment: ♬  *I see by your outfit that you are a cowboy.* ♬

Comment: *“By their fruits shall you know them.”*

Comment: @tchrist But he's asking about "files" not "cowboy outfits" - they are different things!

Answer (score 1):

This usage of 'by' is commonly used, but there may be some restrictions on the pairings of verb and prepositional complement.

> > - I can tell by his frown that he's not going to agree readily.
> > - I can see by the character style that a Chinese person wrote it.
> > - You can see by the look in her eyes....
> > - You can see by the angle of the draws that it is much steeper than my photo makes it look.
> > - You can see by the poster what fantastic Featured Artists The Menace had on her show this month.
> > - I can see by the map you may be a bit secluded; is this true?
>
> (From the internet; grammar / punctuation adjusted.)

This 'by' means 'by considering / taking careful note of'.

I've not been able to find the exact sense in a dictionary, but Macmillan has the following sense for ['from'](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/from):

> **from** 6b used for giving the reason for a judgment or opinion
>
> - *I can tell from your eyes you’re a good man.*
> - *From what I hear, Mr. Marlow is not a man to be trusted.*

The defining statement fits well for this sense of 'by', and 'by' may replace 'from' in the first example (but not the second).

The examples using 'by' above become less fully acceptable, at least to many Brits, towards the latter ones. These have (example 4) non-personally related concepts and (5 and 6) concrete sources of information. 'File' arguably comes into this category (though it might be argued to refer metonymically to 'the information contained in your file').

A venerable example of this usage of *by* is the famous quote from *Macbeth*

- By the pricking of my thumbs ... Something wicked this way comes.

The 'I can tell' is not hard to retrieve, the NP after 'by' contains an **ing**-word ... but it's essentially the same usage. And, referring to a discernable human phenomenon (as well as being written by You-know-who), acceptable across the board.

With diagrams, features in diagrams, posters, maps etc, 'from' is not so generally acceptable; 'from' is doubtless more idiomatic. 'In' would work well with files, letters, written articles and the like.

Comment: The OP didn't ask about "I see by his frown/the character style/the look in her eyes/the angle of vision/the poster on the wall..." They asked about "I see by your file...". Hence I don't see the relevance of your answer.

Comment: 'I often come across some sentences with "by" where I would expect "in" or "on". '  I've supplied some parallel examples, and looked at (admittedly not comprehensively) the distribution of this particular usage, using largely examples fron the internet. Better than an answer just mentioning how idiomatic one felt a particular sentence is, perhaps.

Comment: But if you were interviewing someone, would you say "I see by your file/application/etc that you speak Swahili"?  I wouldn't. It would be "I see from your file..."

Comment: Yes; I'm not contesting your pronunciation on the idiomaticity (/otherwise) of this particular example, and agree that it's likely the prevailing attitude in the UK. But without substantiating references (and I concede that I myself couldn't do much better than internet examples (there are plenty) that remains opinion. Eddie Kal is based in the States, and the internet reflects general usage over there better than my personal opinion / preference. // I believe that broadening to other 'I can tell/see by NP' examples, & trying to analyse, is valid ... even required, and certainly instructive.

Comment: Which is why I pointed out in my answer that I couldn't necessarily speak for Americans, who often use different prepositions to us. Indeed any Briton attempting to pass themselves off as American, or vice-versa, will more likely be undone by their choice of prepositions than by anything else - I would argue.

Answer (score 1):

"By" is correct. Grammatically, with a substantive as an object, it forms an instrumental modifier. It meaning is contextual but is usually informs you of who did something and/or the way in which something was done or how the action of the verb was caused, e.g. "by the means of" or "by the use of" or "with the assistance of".

"It was broken by a man with a hammer."

To quote the famous song by The Bee Gees "Stayin' Alive".

> Well, you can tell **by** the way I use my walk
>
> I'm a woman's man, no time to talk ...

OED

> by, preposition
>
> General scheme of signification.
>
> I. Of position in space: 
>   (1) Position or action near, including notions of comparison by juxtaposition; (2) Direction and vague localization.
>
> II. Of motion in space: (1) Motion alongside, along, or over a course; (2) Motion up to; (3) Motion alongside and beyond, including notions of distance to reach, and of excess, short-coming, or inferiority.
>
> III. Of time.
>
> IV. Of mental or ideal proximity.
>
> V. **Of medium, means, instrumentality, agency.**
>
> VI. Of circumstance, condition, manner, cause.
>
> VII. In phrases.

Answer (score 0):

For me it would nearly always be:

*I see **from** your file...*

Very much second or third choices would be *in* or *on*.

I would never use *by* in this context.

However please be aware that I am British, and Americans often have very different ideas about which prepositions to use
.

Comment: Matthew 7:19-20 Every tree that bringeth not forth good fruit is hewn down, and cast into the fire. Wherefore by their fruits ye shall know them.

Comment: @tchrist I don't see the relevance of the quotation. I would agree, for example, that a person should be judged **"by** their performance". But the questioner was asking about information "by files". I am simply saying that information "**from** files" sounds more idiomatic to me.

Answer (score 0):

In almost all of the "I see by" sentences there is an implied word (or words) that is understood but not written in.

I see by [looking at/reading] your resume ...